# does it make sense to replace plastic flex ducts with metal ducts?

Tags: hvac, ducts

Today I get my ducts cleaned. It's extremely dirty. And I noticed my house which was built at 2003 was using plastic flex ducts.

I just feel metal duct are stronger and easier to clean and never broke.

So does it make sense to replace the plastic ducts with metal? Can I do it by myself usually? I mean do I need permit or inspection? My plan is to slowly replace them by myself.

Any comment is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Metal will require insulation on the outside if it's in unconditioned space; not hard to do. A plus would be metal ducts have less air resistance because of the smooth sides. I am not aware of a need for a permit for duct work.